# Parsing CSV File with \" in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, csv

I'm using VB's TextField in C# to parse a CSV file. But I am getting an error when it gets to \"

```
using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csvFilePath)) {
    csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
    csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
    string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
    foreach (string column in colFields)
    {
        DataColumn datacolumn = new DataColumn(column);
        datacolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
        csvData.Columns.Add(datacolumn);
    }
    while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
    {
        string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
        {
            if (fieldData[i] == "")
            {
                fieldData[i] = null;
            }
        }
        csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
    }
}
```

And this is the line in the csv that is causing the error:

```
"101","Brake System","Level should be between \"MIN\" and \"MAX\" marks."
```

I don't know how to deal with the \" in C# using TextFieldParser

Comment: I don't think using \" to represent " inside a text field isn't the way a CSV file is usually created. Excel would write "Level should be between ""MIN"" and ""MAX"" marks.". Do you have the option of creating the file the standard way?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but using `TextFieldParser` is not recommended as it's very slow.  You'd have better luck using just `String.Split()` or if you have more complicated needs [CSVHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) is a great library with good peformance.

Comment: I don't have an option to reformat the file unfortunately.

Comment: [TextFieldParser is indeed very slow](http://ctl-global.github.io/data.html#benchmark), would not recommend using it for large files.

Answer (score 2):

If the csv file will fit into memory, you could read it in, replace each `\"` with `""`, and use a MemoryStream as the input to the the TextFieldParser:

```
string data = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\csvdata.txt").Replace("\\\"", "\"\"");

//TODO: Use the correct Encoding.
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)))
{
    using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(ms))
    {
        csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
        csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
        string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
        foreach (string s in colFields)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Which, for your example data, outputs

> 101
>   Brake System
>   Level should be between "MIN" and "MAX" marks.

Comment: This is a good solution if my files weren't so large unfortunately I get an out of memory exception when I use this.

Comment: @tasha420 You could read, say, 10,000 lines at a time and process them. Assuming there are no line breaks in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it using two different methods without using `TextFieldParser`.  `TextFieldParser` is very slow and not recommended for use in an actual production application.

Here's the simpler method using just `String` methods, and assuming that it's delimited with `,` without any quotes or any other special CSV formatting.

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("myfile.csv");
using (TextReader reader = file.OpenText())
{
    for(String line = reader.ReadLine(); line != null; line = reader.ReadLine())
    {
         string[] fields = line.Split(new[] {','});
         foreach(String f in fields)
         {
             //do whatever you need for each field
          }
     }
 }
```

Now if you want to use [CsvHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) (available on nuget) becaues you have a more complicated CSV file with things like quoted field, headers, or if the rows of your CSV can map directly to an object that you have then this library might help you.

Not Mapped Example:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("myfile.csv");
using (TextReader reader = file.OpenText())
using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader))
{
     csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
     csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
     csv.Configuration.IgnoreQuotes = true; //if you don't use field quoting
     csv.Configuration.TrimFields = true; //trim fields as you read them
     csv.Configuration.WillThrowOnMissingField = false; //otherwise null fields aren't allowed

     while(csv.Read())
     {
          myStringVar = csv.GetField<string>(0); //gets first field as string
          myIntVar = csv.GetField<int>(1); //gets second field as int
          ... //etc, you get the idea

     }
}
```

Mapped Example:

Mapping Class- Assumes you have a class named `MyClass` with the fields named field1, field2, field3

```
public sealed class MyClassMap : CsvClassMap<MyClass>
{
     public MyClassMap()
     {
         Map(m => m.field1).Index(0);
         Map(m => m.field2).Index(1);
         Map(m => m.field3).Index(2);
     }
 }
```

Parsing Code

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("myfile.csv");
using (TextReader reader = file.OpenText())
using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader))
{
     csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
     csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
     csv.Configuration.IgnoreQuotes = true; //if you don't use field quoting
     csv.Configuration.TrimFields = true; //trim fields as you read them
     csv.Configuration.WillThrowOnMissingField = false; //otherwise null fields aren't allowed
     csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<MyClassMap>(); //adds our mapping class to the reader

     while(csv.Read())
     {
         myObject = csv.GetRecord<MyClass>();
         //do whatever here
     }
}
```

Both of these methods won't care that you have any strange characters like `\` in your csv file.

*Disclaimer: I have no relation to CsvHelper, but have had success with it in a few projects in the past in which it has made my life much easier*

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a different library, [Ctl.Data](http://ctl-global.github.io/data.html) has a mode (`parseMidQuotes: true`) specifically to allow parsing broken CSV like this.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("data.csv"))
{
    var reader = new CsvReader<Record>(sr, parseMidQuotes: true, readHeader: false);

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Record rec = reader.CurrentObject.Value;
        rec.Description = rec.Description.Replace("\\\"", "\"");

        // use record...
    }
}
```

And define your `Record` object:

(Normally it would match the header of the file to the properties, but in your case with a headerless file you need to specify the order with the `Column` attribute.

```
class Record
{
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

(Disclaimer: I'm the author of said library)